# How to resolve the slow performance in nested loop

Tags: laravel-7, laravel-api

I have a nested loop in my controller when i have 100+ it get slow and get error `maximum exceed time` so i need to return the result quickly what can i do to get that list of array,

```
public function DeviceStatus(Request $request)
{
    $queryinput =$request->deviceNumber;
    $idsArray =explode(" ", $queryinput);
    //dd($idsArray);
    // $jsonData = [];
    foreach ($idsArray as $key=>$id) {
        try {
            $response = Http::get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/extapi/v12/DeviceData/ByDeviceDataNumber/'.$id.'');
            $jsonData = $response->json();
            $deviceStatus[$id] = $jsonData;
        } catch (\Exception $exception) {
            // toastr()->Error($exception->getMessage());
            return back()->withError($exception->getMessage());
        }
        //dd($idsArray);
        return view('tracedevice.ectsdevicestatus',compact('deviceStatus'));
    }
```

Comment: That looks like your old code. Your `foreach` will `return view('tr...` after the first iteration and not process any further. You make 100+ requests to your API server (what's with the `http://http://` btw?) - this might take some time. Split up your requests, make 50 requests twice

Comment: @brombeer,,i edited my code i have one http:// instead of two,

Comment: How can i devide there?

Comment: Can i use something like this `foreach($idArray->chunk(50) as $id){} ?

Comment: @brombeer any idea of this ?